# Can we write the IN clause in ELSE IF statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

I am writing a scalar-valued function and to that function I am passing email and methodID and it will return INT and now I need to check condition depending on methodID so that I have return as shown below

```
ALTER FUNCTION FN_EMPCHECK
(
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(150),
    @methodID INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsResult INT

    IF(@methodID = 101)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table1 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END
    ELSE IF(@methodID = 102 OR @methodID = 104 OR @methodID = 105 OR @methodID = 107 OR @methodID = 108
                OR @methodID = 109 OR @methodID = 110 OR @methodID = 111 OR @methodID = 114)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table2 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END
    ELSE IF(@methodID = 103 OR @methodID = 106 OR @methodID = 112 OR @methodID = 113)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table3 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END

    RETURN @IsResult
END
```

Need suggestions regarding Else If statement in the above function weather it is the correct manner or I can write in any another simple way (Writing many OR conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **IN** instead of multiple **OR** operators in your ELSE IF conditions, check below code

```
ALTER FUNCTION FN_EMPCHECK
(
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(150),
    @methodID INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsResult INT

    IF(@methodID = 101)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table1 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END
    ELSE IF(@methodID IN (102, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 114))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table2 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END
    ELSE IF(@methodID IN (103 ,106, 112, 113))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table3 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
    END

    RETURN @IsResult
END
```

Comment: Having a doubt will it work or not. Now it is clear. working fine. Thank you @Saharsh Shah

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use **IN** in If statement

```
ALTER FUNCTION FN_EMPCHECK
(
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(150),
    @methodID INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IsResult INT

IF(@methodID = 101)
BEGIN
    SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table1 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
END
ELSE IF @methodID IN (102, 104, 105, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 114)
BEGIN
    SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table2 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
END
ELSE IF @methodID IN (103 ,106, 112, 113)
BEGIN
    SELECT @IsResult = ID FROM table3 WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress
END

RETURN @IsResult
END
```